# unable to upload files

Tags: php, file-upload

This is my script:-

```
if (isset($_POST['confirm_close_complaint_submit']))
{
    if($_FILES['complaint_file']['tmp_name'] == "none")
    {
        header('Location: complaint-register.php?FileSizeError=1');
        exit();
    }
    $filename = basename($_FILES['complaint_file']['name']);
    $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);
    if (($ext != "jpg") && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] != "image/jpeg"))
    {
        header('Location: complaint-register.php?FileTypeError=1');
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        $destination = '../../stored/complaint-files/'.$_POST['confirm_close_complaint'].$_FILES['complaint_file']['name'];
        $temp_file = $_FILES['complaint_file']['temp_name'];
        move_uploaded_file($temp_file, $destination);
        $insertSQL = sprintf("UPDATE complaints SET complaint_status='CLOSED', complaint_solved_date=NOW(), complaint_remark=%s WHERE complaint_number=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['complaint_remark'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['confirm_close_complaint'], "text"));
        $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $dacreint) or die(mysql_error());  
        header('Location: complaint-register.php?ComplaintClose=Successful');
        exit();
    }
}
```

This script do the mysql insertion but do not upload the file. It shows me successful message.

Here is my form:-

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="complaint-register.php">
    <table border="0">
    <tr>
    <td>Remark</td>
    <td><textarea name="complaint_remark" class="textarea"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Complaint File</td>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
        <input name="complaint_file" type="file" size="100" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <input name="confirm_close_complaint" type="hidden" value="'.$close_complaint.'" />
    <input name="confirm_close_complaint_submit" type="submit" class="Button" style="float:left;" value="Yes" />
    <input name="" type="button" class="Button" style="float:left;" onClick="javascript:history.go(-1)" value="No" />
    </form>
```

Is the way i am defining the path is correct i.e. `$destination = '../../stored/complaint-files/'.$_POST['confirm_close_complaint'].$_FILES['complaint_file']['name'];`??

And do this condition is ok `$temp_file = $_FILES['complaint_file']['tmp_name'];`

Comment: Is there sth more revelant in `$_FILES['complaint_file']['error']` ?

Comment: An aside, but including an unchecked `$_POST` variable in your destination could be dangerous since they are relatively easy to spoof.

Comment: @Philip Actually `$_POST['confirm_close_complaint']` coming from disabled textbox, that's why i didn't do that... still its better to do it.... thanks

Comment: @j0k Ok i did `if ($_FILES["complaint_file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
  }
else
  { Something
}`

Now let me check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$_FILES['complaint_file']['temp_name'];
```

should be

```
$_FILES['complaint_file']['tmp_name'];
```

Add your update statement inside if uploaded, like

```
if(move_uploaded_file($temp_file, $destination)) {
  //your update statement here
}
else {
  //error
}
```

Try to check if your destination path is valid.
Set error reporting on:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Ok it did it but still the file is not getting uploaded.

Comment: Ok i did this check and its not doing the script now, its showing me my manual created error message. What would be the reason???

Comment: I did it and it shows me my manual created error... the condition `if(move_uploaded_file($temp_file, $destination))` did not get satisfied and it jumped to `else` condition. What would be the reason??

Comment: the $destination might not be valid path or check if the destination folder has write permissions, these can be the reason, set error_reporting and you might be able to see the error

Answer (score 1):

Try handling errors from move_uploaded_file. You should not show a "success" message of that call fails.

Comment: I did it and it shows me my manual created error... the condition `if(move_uploaded_file($temp_file, $destination))` did not get satisfied and it jumped to `else` condition. What would be the reason??